# Do we actually know the charges of quarks?

Tags: charge, quarks

It is well known that quarks have a charge of either 2/3e or -1/3e depending on quark. What is the evidence behind that?

Did someone simply write $q_u+q_u+q_d=q_{proton}=1e$ and $q_u+q_d+q_d=q_{neutron}=0$ and solve it? If so, why do we assume that the total charge is the sum of the parts? It's clearly not the case with mass. Maybe some charge is added or lost because of the binding interaction?

Answer (score 0):

charges of quarks 1/3 and 2/3 (they were initially called partons) come from the experiments in 1960th when high energy electrons were scattered on protons. Friedman, Kendall and Taylor were awarded the Nobel prize in 1990